# Setting custom key names for exported JSON view fields

Tags: views, 9

I have a result set similar to this (using Views RESTful Export):

[image: views exported as JSON]

My question, how to change `created_1` key and name it something else?

Comment: From views? Have you implemented your own Normalizer class?

Comment: Yes, but seems that the Normalizer class alters the `Entity` display format not `Fields`. Can Normalizer be used to alter field output?

Comment: I've only ever used Entity on a view with normalizer. The other upside is if you serialize an entity from code elsewhere, it will be formatted the same way through the normalizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From views you can configure the custom name/alias for fields from **Fields | Settings** option under **Format**.
Check the screenshot for reference
[image]

Comment: Could not be simpler than that, thank you.